# Plotting non-injective labels on vertices in a graph in SageMath

Tags: plot, sage

I have a graph with vertices labeled by some pairs (a,b).
Can I plot it in such a way that I only see the first component "a" printed over each vertex?
I cannot just relabel, since my map (a,b)->a is not injective.

For a small example, take

```
G = Graph()
G.add_edge((1,1),(1,2))
```

The usual `G.plot()` gives (1,1)---(1,2).
Instead, how to produce only 1---1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Plot a Sage graph with non-injective vertex labals

We describe a slightly tedious workaround, and then
a way to recover our comfort.

#### New class for vertices

One solution consists in writing a new class for vertices
that inherits from `tuple` and has a custom `__str__` method
that returns a string for only the first entry in the tuple.

```
class MyVertex(tuple):
    r"""
    Class for vertices for special plotting of graphs.

    Use with tuples, and only the first entry in the tuple
    will be used as a vertex label when plotting the graph.
    """
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.vertex = v

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.vertex[0])
```

Using this to define the vertices of the graph,
we obtain the desired behaviour.

Define a graph and add an edge from `(1, 1)` to `(1, 2)`:

```
sage: G = Graph()
sage: G.add_edge(MyVertex((1, 1)), MyVertex((1, 2)))
```

When plotting the graph, both vertices have the label `1`.

```
sage: G.plot()
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 4 graphics primitives
```

When listing the vertices, they still appear fully:

```
sage: G.vertices()
[(1, 1), (1, 2)]
```

#### Using usual graphs

To avoid having to use `MyVertex` explicitly, we write a graph-plotting
function that creates an intermediate "MyVertex"-style copy of a usual graph
for the sake of plotting.

```
def plot_graph(G):
    r"""
    Return a plot of this graph with special vertex labels.

    The graph vertices are assumed to be tuples. The plot
    uses the first component of each tuple as a vertex label.
    """
    E = [(MyVertex(a), MyVertex(b)) for (a, b) in G.edges(labels=False)]
    return Graph(E).plot()
```

Now compare:

```
sage: G = graphs.Grid2dGraph(3, 4)
sage: G.plot()
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 30 graphics primitives
sage: plot_graph(G)
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 30 graphics primitives
```